# Can I use NormalPValue the same way for lower-tail and upper-tail hypothesis tests?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to ask if I can use the **NormalPValue[val]** the same way for lower-tail and upper-tail hypothesis tests or if there is something I need to watch out for? Personally, my gut feeling is that I need to substract the P-Value from 1 for the other kind of test.

Here's an example to show what I'm talking about:

*A software reduced the amount of spam of 100 messages to 11%. This is better than the goal of 20%. Based on a significance level of 0.05, is this significant or not? I.e. buy the software or not?*

1. We state the following hypotheses:

> H0: p >= p0 = 0.20
>
> H1: p < p0 = 0.20
>
> Further use [Alpha] = 0.05.

2. Since we test a proportion we have to use the z-statistic:

   phead = 0.11;

   p0 = 0.20;

   n = 100;

   zcalc = (phead - p0) / (Sqrt[p0 * (1 - p0) / n])

   **-2.25**
3. Calculate the P-Value
   Needs["HypothesisTesting`"];

   NormalPValue[zcalc]

   **OneSidedPValue -> 0.0122245**
4. Compare P-Value to [Alpha]

   Since The P-Value of 0.0122245 is smaller than our [Alpha] = 0.05, we reject H0 and accept the alternative hypothesis H1. The manager should buy the software.

---

My question now is, if we were to use the following H0/H1 instead (for a different kind of task, of course):

> H0: p <= p0 = 0.20
>
> H1: p > p0 = 0.20

Am I correct that in this case, I would receive the P-Value as follows:

1 - 0.0122245 = 0.9877755

And would therefore not be able to reject H0?

Comment: This site is about the programming environment "Mathematica" not about mathematics and statistics in general. You might want to take a gander at [crossvalidated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com) for questions about statistics.

Comment: @Sascha My question stems from Mathematica, since unlike when using TTest (reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TTest.html) there is no option to define whether it's a lower-tail or upper-tail test in the OneSidedPValue[val] function. I.e. I don't understand what OneSidedPValue returns and how to properly use it.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reflect what you stated in your comment.

Comment: There are some issues with the example you've used.  The distribution that is assumed is a binomial distribution and the "exact" answer for the first set of hypotheses is `CDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 0.2], 11]`.  For the second set of hypotheses the answer is `1 - CDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 0.1], 10]` which is not "1 minus the first probability".  A "*P*-value" is the probability of obtaining at least as extreme a value as observed.  (I've ignored the complication that you have a compound hypothesis for the null hypothesis.)

Comment: If your underlying distribution was continuous, then, yes, the *P*-values would be 1 minus the other.  Also, in that case you could use `LocationTest` which does have an option for a one-sided alternative hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (thanks to some help from a colleague in real life): Yes, it is correct, since we need to get the opposite area of the normal distribution area.